# insert data using prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql

hello guy i want to insert data from radio,checkbox, input and image file using prepare statement in PHP but if a run the program it bring me this error message which I don't understand

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on
> bool in /opt/lampp/htdocs/nesthet/backend/test_result_script.php:63
> Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/nesthet/test_result.php(2):
> include() #1 {main} thrown in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/nesthet/backend/test_result_script.php on line 63

here are my php codes

```
    <?php
    include 'server-connection.php';

    //database connection
    $db = mysqli_select_db($con,'nesthet');

    if(isset($_POST['insert']))
    {
        //declaration of variables
        //personal data
        
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];

        //vital section

        $blood_pressure = $_POST['blood_pressure'];
        $temperature = $_POST['temperature'];
        $heart_rate = $_POST['heart_rate'];
        $respiratory_rate = $_POST['respiratory_rate'];
        $oxygen_saturation = $_POST['oxygen_saturation'];

        //examination section

        $general_condition = $_POST['general_condition'];
        //checkbox data capture
        $option = $_POST['optional_disease'];
        $optional_disease = implode (',',$option);

        $jaundice = $_POST['jaundice'];
        $edema = $_POST['edema'];

        //routine lab test

        $random_blood_sugar = $_POST['random_blood_sugar'];
        $fast_blood_sugar = $_POST['fast_blood_sugar'];
        $hemoglobin = $_POST['hemoglobin'];
        $blood_group = $_POST['blood_group'];
        $rapid_diagnosis_test = $_POST['rapid_diagnosis_test'];
        $white_blood_cell = $_POST['white_blood_cell'];

        //investigation

        $image_tittle = $_POST['image_tittle'];
        
        //image insertion
        $picture_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $upload = "uploaded_files/".$picture_name;

        // tests and test results
        $first_test = $_POST['first_test'];
        $f_test_result = $_POST['f_test_result'];
        $second_test = $_POST['second_test'];
        $s_test_result = $_POST['s_test_result'];
        $third_test = $_POST['third_test'];
        $t_test_result = $_POST['t_test_result'];

        

        //sql injection security using prepared statement
        $query = "INSERT into tbl_test_result(name , telephone , blood_pressure , temperature , heart_rate , respiratory_rate , oxygen_saturation , general_condition , optional_disease , jaundice , edema , random_blood_sugar , fast_blood_sugar , hemoglobin , blood_group , rapid_diagnosis_test , white_blood_cell , image_tittle , picture_name , first_test , f_test_result , second_test , s_test_result , third_test , t_test_result)values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssssssssss",$name , $telephone , $blood_pressure , $temperature , $heart_rate , $respiratory_rate , $oxygen_saturation , $general_condition , $optional_disease , $jaundice , $edema , $random_blood_sugar , $fast_blood_sugar , $hemoglobin , $blood_group , $rapid_diagnosis_test , $white_blood_cell , $image_tittle , $upload , $first_test , $f_test_result , $second_test , $s_test_result , $third_test , $t_test_result);
        $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Fatal error* clearly points you to the line where you use: `bind_param()`. The error states that the function cannot be used on a `bool` (boolean).

```
/** problem here: **/
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssss...
```

So: `$stmt` is a `boolean` - so you cannot use `$stmt->bind_param` - why is that? You have to check the line above it: `$stmt = $con->prepare($query);` What happens here?

If you check the PHP manual [mysqli_prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) it says that its *Return Values* are:

> mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error
> occurred.

So, in your case, it clearly returned FALSE (i.e. a `boolean`) which means *you have an error in your query*.

Conclusion: your `$query` contains an error. But where? You have to check the *table name*, *columns' names* etc.

For example, I see you use in your query: `image_tittle` -> shouldn't this be: "image_title"? Try to correct this and see if it works.

I would also recommend to check if the query is ok, before anything:

```
$query = "...";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);

if (!$stmt) {
   /** manage this error */
   echo "Error - query not valid!";
   exit;
}
```

(I hope the long answer helps - I tried to show you how to debug your code for the future)